# compile error of camera1394 on fuerte

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I checked out the package from svn and then compiled with the following error:

```
 cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package camera_1394
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
  MSG: gencfg_cpp on:Camera1394.cfg
  Finding dependencies for /root/ros_workspace/camera_1394/cfg/Camera1394.cfg
  ***********************************************************************************
  load_module did not return. Unable to determine dependencies for file listed above.
  ***********************************************************************************
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/gendeps", line 64, in <module>
      imp.load_module("__main__", f, srcfile, ('.cfg', 'U', 1))
    File "/root/ros_workspace/camera_1394/cfg/Camera1394.cfg", line 37, in <module>
      import roslib; roslib.load_manifest(PACKAGE)
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
      sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
    File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
      m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 118, in get_manifest
      return self._load_manifest(name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 157, in _load_manifest
      retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 149, in get_path
      raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
  rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: camera1394
  ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
  ROS path [1]=/root/ros_workspace
  ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
  ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
  ROS path [4]=/Downloads/drivers
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:68 (string):
    string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:89 (gencfg_cpp)
    CMakeLists.txt:22 (include)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

how can i solve this?thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40278/compile-error-of-camera1394-on-fuerte/) by [yolandazcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/2955/yolandazcc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-31**:
Could you please reformat your console output listing? If you prefix each line with '    ' (4 spaces) it wil preserve formatting, making it much easier to read. See also [markdown/syntax/](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect you have not [installed all the new Python scripts](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu#Standalone_tools) needed for compiling packages with Fuerte.

In particular, it looks like you are missing the new `rosdep` script.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0